# Superpose two boxplots with a different number of data in only one graph

Tags: r, boxplot

In r, is there a solution to superpose two boxplots in only one graph with a different number of data?
(With a different color for data1 and data2)

Rather than doing this :

```
data1 <- data.frame(T1_A=rnorm(37),T2_A=rnorm(37),T3_A=rnorm(37))
data2 <- data.frame(T1_B=rnorm(25),T2_B=rnorm(25),T3_B=rnorm(25))
par(mfrow = c(2,1)
boxplot(data1)
boxplot(data2)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Row bind your data frames together, introducing a new column to define which data frame the row came from.  Use this new column to define the colour.  There's a missing closing parenthesis in your sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ggplot, you can achieve the same effect like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(pivot_longer(data1, everything()),
          pivot_longer(data2, everything()),
          .id = 'dataset') %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~dataset, nrow = 2, scales = 'free_x', drop = TRUE)
```

[image]

Or if you want them all in the same panel,

```r
bind_rows(pivot_longer(data1, everything()),
          pivot_longer(data2, everything()),
          .id = 'dataset') %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Base option:**

You could create use `boxplot` calls where the second has `add=true` to combine them in one graph. With `at` you can define the colnames on the x-axis like this:

```r
data1 <- data.frame(T1_A=rnorm(37),T2_A=rnorm(37),T3_A=rnorm(37))
data2 <- data.frame(T1_B=rnorm(25),T2_B=rnorm(25),T3_B=rnorm(25))
boxplot(data1, at = 0:2*3+1, border = "red", xlim = c(0,9))
boxplot(data2, at = 0:2*3+2, border = "blue", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>